# D3 Map data label not correctly showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to display a map that when hovered over it displays the state name and the data tied to state as specified by my data object.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/ORqwEL?editors=1010

My problem is getting the data to properly show after the state name text -- I am merely getting an undefined variable. The data simply shows nothing. I have no idea how to properly get that data because I thought this method would work. Here is how it's calling the data:

```
... AT LINE 353 of CODEPEN LINK
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
        var html = "";

        html += "<div class=\"tooltip_kv\">";
        html += "<span class=\"tooltip_key\">";
        html += id_name_map[d.id];
        html += "</span>";
        html += "<span class=\"tooltip_value\">";
        html += valueById.get(d.id);
        html += "";
        html += "</span>";
        html += "</div>";

        $("#tooltip-container").html(html);
        $(this).attr("fill-opacity", "0.8");
        $("#tooltip-container").show(); ...
```

I don't understand why it's displaying undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing the properties of the data properly.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  // d doesn't have the properties MAP_STATE and MAP_VALUE
  var id = name_id_map[d[MAP_STATE]];  // change to d[0][0]
  valueById.set(id, +d[MAP_VALUE]);  // change to d[1][1]
});
```

Also change in the quantize method. That should solve your problem